# HTTP not found custom exception in asp.net web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using this code source from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/handling-http-404-error-aspnet) to display the custom 404 with detailed error message in my application. 
But the ActionSelector does not work and throw the null exception in **request**

```
public class HttpNotFoundAwareControllerActionSelector : ApiControllerActionSelector
    {
        public HttpNotFoundAwareControllerActionSelector()
        {
        }

        public override HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            HttpActionDescriptor decriptor = null;
            try
            {
                decriptor = base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
            }
            catch (HttpResponseException ex)
            {
                var code = ex.Response.StatusCode;
                if (code != HttpStatusCode.NotFound && code != HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed)
                    throw;
                var routeData = controllerContext.RouteData;
                routeData.Values["action"] = "Handle404";
                IHttpController httpController = new ErrorController();
                controllerContext.Controller = httpController;
                controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor = new HttpControllerDescriptor(controllerContext.Configuration, "Error", httpController.GetType());
                decriptor = base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
            }
            return decriptor;
        }
    }
```

This is my HttpError controller

```
public class ErrorController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpHead, HttpOptions, AcceptVerbs("PATCH")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Handle404()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, Logger.ConditionWarning("Invalid API Request - 404 Not Found"));
            return response;
        }
    }
```

It seems that SelectAction not forwarding the request to controller? Please help

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED : Try this

```
    public class ErrorController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpHead, HttpOptions, AcceptVerbs("PATCH")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Handle404()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            message.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(HttpResponseMessage), Logger.ConditionWarning("Invalid API Request - 404 Not Found"), GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
            return message
        }
    }
```

Comment: The "request" is null. So using CreateResponse and CreateErrorResponse doesn't make any difference. Same error.

Comment: can you please try that ?

Comment: What is MessageResponse here, i can't find any reference namespace for that?

Comment: ohh sorry it is `HttpResponseMessage`,

Comment: That worked, the only difference is I had to use my error object instead of HttpResponseMessage. In my case it was CustomError.